# How to access callout view on clicking on map annotation using swift in xctest

Tags: swift, xcode, xcuitest, xctestcase, callouts

I want to access callout views and do some `UIAutomation` on those views. I'm able to click on map markers/annotations but not able to access the callout view.
The following code used to tap on the marker:

```
let marker = app.otherElements.matching(identifier: "mapMarker").element(boundby: 0)
marker.tap();
```

After this, I'm getting the callout view of the respected marker/annotation.
I need to access that callout.
Please suggest me on this.

Comment: Does the callout view have an accessibility identifier?

Comment: The callout view is also taking the same identifier as the marker/annotation is having.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a breakpoint after the callout is snown,
then type `po print(app.debugDescription)` (or simply `po app` in XCode 11) in `lldb` in order to view the whole hierarchy of UI elements.

Locate the needed element and access it further in code.

Also, consider rewriting your marker code in a shorter way:

`let marker = app.otherElements["mapMarker"].firstMatch`

Please notice `firstMatch` aborts search of elements after it found the first one.

Drop `firstMatch`, if you want to check that the element is unique

`let marker = app.otherElements["mapMarker"]`

Comment: I already checked that above po print(app.debugDescription). Callout info is not displaying the UI hierarchy.

Comment: The view should be an accessibility element in order to appear in this hierarchy. This requires to adjust the app code appropriately.  


Please refer to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/supporting_voiceover_in_your_app

Comment: This syntax: `app.otherElements["mapMarker"].firstMatch`: can result in flaky uitests if the model providing the view is backed via a network call. The ["mapMarker"] filter mechanism will only try three times before giving up. You might want to write a method that uses an expectation to wait for the expected elements to appear instead

Answer (score 0):

Same as Smart Monkey said, but to add more code based off the comment from ablarg:

Ex: "mapMarker" being the accessibility ID for the element

```
    let mapMarker = app.maps.otherElements["mapMarker"].firstMatch
    let mapMarkerExists = mapMarker.waitForExistence(timeout: 3)
    if mapMarkerExists {
      mapMarker.tap()
  }
```

`waitForExistence(timeout:)` returns a bool, so if the element appears before the timeout expires (it finds the element) take action (tap) on the element.

Make sure the element is enabled for accessibility and has the accessibility ID set.